# Iterating through typescript map from string to function

Tags: typescript

I have a map that I like to iterate through. It looks like the code sample. Can you give a code example how this works, please?

```
var fnMap = {
  "foo": function() { ... },
  "bar": function() { ... },
  // ...
};
```

Comment: Hey, this isn't a proper map. I see you tagged this as TypeScript, do you mean to use this?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: Because you can iterate through a map using `Array.from(yourMap.keys()).forEach(k => console.log(k));`

Comment: for me is important, that the functions are triggered whenever you iterate through the map. Or is there any other way, how to define a map from string to function with a static type?

Comment: To do that, I think this should work: 

`Array.from(yourMap.keys()).forEach(k => k());`

Also, yes you don't need a map for this, it can be done with an object, but nonetheless the concept is the same. Iterate through and run the function from the object index as in the example above.

Comment: With your current object and [Object.values (ES2017)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values): `Object.values(fnMap).forEach(fn => fn());`.